# How to create footers in CSS

Tags: html, css

I started learning CSS, HTML, and other cool stuff a day ago. I really don't understand why my footer isn't working.

Can you help me to solve my problem, tell me what I'm doing wrong, or just tell me, that I should go play tetris?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QALze/)

**HTML CODE :**

```
<title>MyDotCom</title>
<body>
  <div id="header">My awesome page title, logo, etc.</div>
  <div id="left">Navigation menu</div>
  <div id="bar">Random bar, lol.</div>
  <div id="footer">Coded by: me</div>
  <div id="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Proin nibh augue, suscipit a, scelerisque sed, lacinia in, mi. Cras vel lorem. Etiam pellentesque aliquet tellus. Phasellus pharetra nulla ac diam.
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS CODE :**

```
#header {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #C6E2FF;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#bar {
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #6E4005;
  width: 90%;
  height: 40px;
  float: both;
  margin-left: 10%;
  position: relative;
  z-index:1;
}
#left {
  float:left;
  background-color: #F6C483;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 20%;
  height:400px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
#content {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 80%;
  height: 360px;
  background-color: #F4EBC3;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#footer {
  background-color: #B0B0B0;
  position:absolute;
  clear:both;
  height: 30px;
}
```

I tried to change `position:absolute;` to `position:relative;`, but it didn't work.

It's difficult to ask you for help, because probably it is really simple, but I tried, and tried, and have no idea what to do.

Comment: Regardless of ones coding ability, one should always make time for Tetris.

Comment: plz include your code you linked to in your fiddle, otherwise this might become pretty useless to future readers. besides TETRIS for addition instead of substitution ;)

Comment: And on a more serious note: what are you trying to achieve? Is the footer to take up 100% of the width of the document and sit at the bottom?

Comment: Yeah, 100% width footer on bottom of the page is that what I expect

Comment: Do you want footer ALWAYS VISIBLE, or just simply always bottom of page? Because these are 2 different task. and to make it always bottom of page will either require full content in your body or JavaScript work

Comment: Well, I think it should be visible just on bottom of the page. But there is no problem if it will be in a diffrent way.

Comment: Ryan Fait's [Sticky Footer technique](http://ryanfait.com/html5-sticky-footer/) is the most popular without using a framework. I don't like it because it requires an extra `div` to work, but I'm guessing there isn't a better way or someone would have called him on it.

Comment: Why ppl think so much, Many answers told 'adding bottom:0', Correct answer is @Gatekeeper and so simple. PS: I dont see any word like `Sticky Footer` on this question...

Comment: @l2aelba - yeah, no one thought of that. Genius.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about removing `position: absolute;` and moving your footer below `content` in html?

[modified code](http://jsfiddle.net/QALze/5/)

Comment: Oh! Now it looks like I expected. Really thanks for helping me with this. Sad, because I cant give you "vote up" for help, but keep in mind, that you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few pointers, you need to set either bottom,top,left or right to position an absolute element.

Furthermore, wrap them in a container/wrapper and give it a position relative so the absolutely positioned element doesn't end up in odd places, the position relative forces it to  the dimensions of the wrapper so `bottom:0;` makes it stick to the bottom of the wrapper.

When you float divs inside a container they are taken out of the flow resulting in an inaccurate auto height to the container, that's where the `clear:both;` comes into play.

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/QALze/1/)** is an updated jsfiddle with the fixed applied, and **[here's](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/30-days-to-learn-html-and-css-a-free-tuts-premium-course/)** an awesome tutorial to get you going on the right path.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed position:relative in footer and moved

```
<div id="footer">Coded by: me</div>
```

below content..

http://jsfiddle.net/QALze/7/

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I didn't want to take credit for someone else's work, but if more answers keep popping up that keep showing pieces of the generally accepted solution, my eye is gonna pop.

Source:  [Ryan Fait's HTML5 CSS Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/html5-sticky-footer/)

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <p>Your website content here.</p>
        <div class="push"></div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <p>Copyright (c) 2008</p>
    </footer>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -155px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
footer, .push {
    height: 155px; /* '.push' must be the same height as 'footer' */
}

/*

Sticky Footer by Ryan Fait
http://ryanfait.com/

*/
```

As I said in my comment to the OP, I'm not a huge fan of the technique because it requires a dummy div, but the point of the `.push` div is to match the height of the footer so that content in the primary div does not dip behind the footer and thus become hidden to the user but still visible to the window, which can be a serious pain.